# Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression in vb.net with access 2010

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, types, mismatch

```
 Dim QRY As String = "SELECT t1.Observer_Name,t1.Company, t2.Safety, t2.T_Name, t2.Trainer_Name," _
                               + "t2.T_Location, t2.T_Start, t2.T_End,(DateDiff(""d"",T_Start, T_End)+1)*8 as [Man_Hours], t2.Remarks" _
                               + " FROM ObserverDetails t1,Training t2,TrainningAttendee t3" _
                               + " WHERE t2.T_ID=t3.T_ID AND t3.Ob_ID=t1.Observer_ID And  t2.T_Start >= @dt1 AND t2.T_Start <= @dt2 "
        cmdSelect.CommandText = QRY
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@dt1", OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = DateTimePicker1.Text.Trim
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@dt2", OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = DateTimePicker2.Text.Trim
        cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdSelect.Connection = reportConnection4

        reader1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader
        If reader1.Read Then
            While reader1.Read
                Dim row As String() = New String() {" " & reader1.Item("Observer_Name") & " ", "" & reader1.Item("Company") & "", " " & reader1.Item("Safety") & " ", " " & reader1.Item("T_Name") & "", _
                                                   "" & reader1.Item("Trainer_Name") & " ", " " & reader1.Item("T_Location") & "", "" & reader1.Item("T_Start") & "", _
                                                   "" & reader1.Item("T_End") & " ", "" & reader1.Item("Man_Hours") & " ", "" & reader1.Item("Remarks") & " "}
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
            End While
        End If
```

giving me error
at **reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader**
error is **Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**

Comment: Where is the relevant part, namely the declaration of `reader1`?

Comment: you appear to be evaluating dates as text...that likely wont end well.  if `T_Start` is a date column that would explain the data mismatch with the text passed.

Comment: ya it is declared at the start of Public Sub

Comment: In your database what is the datatype of the field T_Start?

Comment: this logic is working for different form @Plutonix

Comment: @Steve its Date/Time of MS Access

Comment: you are passing text - `DTP.Text` and wanting the DB to treat it as a `Date` in the WHERE clause.  That is the meaning of the error.  Comparing Dates in Text form wont work long term "9/1/1900" will evaluate larger than "12/31/2015" beause "9" is more than "1".  Use dates to do date related ops.

Comment: Could you show us what is the value of DateTimePicker1.Text end DateTimePicker2.Text?

Answer (score 1):

If your command is a `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand` then your reader must be a `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader` or a base type of it (`DbDataReader` or `IDataReader`).

```
Dim reader1 As OleDbDataReader
```

Or implicitly

```
Dim reader1 = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
```

---

You can use `AddWithValue` in order to a a parameter with the right type auotmatically. If your database type is Date/Time then pass the date as `Date` not as string (as others have said in comments).

```
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", DateTimePicker1.Value)
```

The problem with strings is (in addition to the data type mismatch) that a textual representation of a date is always dependent on the culture used for formatting. If the DB assumes another culture, then things might go wrong US 5/7/2014 (m/d/yyyy) is not the same as British 5/7/2014 (d/m/yyyy)!

Comment: its OleDbDataReader only

Comment: `System.Data.OleDb` is the namespace that you probably have imported and therefore not specified in the `Dim` statement.